# How to forward my service from localhost to the internet?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, localhost, telnet

I have made my personal tcp service that works on port `44444` through telnet as a communication protocol. The service itself is just a simple guess game written in C. I am working on Fedora Linux and using `xinetd` daemon to handle the telnet requests.

**Steps:** I've defined my service inside `/etc/services` and created service's configuration inside `/etc/xinetd.d` and also had to open the port `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 44444 -j ACCEPT` and finally had to restart `xinetd` itself.

Looking from client's standpoint it works like this:

```
[root@localhost]# telnet localhost 44444
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Guess the number between 1 and 100
Your guess: 50
Higher than 50!
Your guess: 75
Congrats, you found the number! Took you 2 tries
Bye bye

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**Problem:** I want to let other people on the internet temporarily access my service by using my IP. They should be able to write `telnet 55.66.77.88 44444` where `55.66.77.88` would be my exemplary IP.

**Question:** How do I allow that? How do I forward my localhost / port 44444 to the Internet?

I am new to networking's vocabulary so quite not sure how to google my issue. If you have suggestions, let me know. Please don't tell me to use ssh instead of telnet, as I'm just experimenting and it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your service is running on a PC that is connected to the Internet through NAT (Network Address Translation) on a home router. In this scenario, you must tell your router to [forward a port](https://portforward.com/) (it is hilarious that there is an entire domain dedicated to this). The actual process is usually pretty simple. Telnet uses TCP to communicate, so you will want to define a forwarded port on your router that directs TCP traffic to port 44444 on your PC. The actual implementation varies depending on the router and its UI, but the key elements are right there: PC IP address, PC listening port, router external port to forward (*it's worth noting that you can choose any external port to forward--port forwarding translates address:port <-> address:port*).

Depending on your router, you may *also* need to specifically allow such traffic through the firewall. Again, this will depend on the implementation.

Also note that testing this setup from inside your local network **may or may not work correctly** depending on whether your router supports [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (asking the router to send traffic out the front gate, turn right back around and enter back in through a different port). If it does not, you will need to test it from a non-local site--perhaps a cloud VM.

Last, although this example is not likely to be of you to you directly (unless you're behind a Cisco ASA), the IOS command would be something like:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.101 44444 55.66.77.88 44444 extendable
```